# NetSuite browser performance

Tags: performance, google-chrome, firefox, netsuite

I'm helping someone work with NetSuite, and the client-side performance is not very good for functions that have a lot of client-side data. We're currently using Chrome Version 58, but have also tried Firefox.

The NetSuite browser client code is pretty heavy, and it downloads/caches a fair bit of data on occasion, which slows things down more on the client side (we've verified the slow-down is on the client, not the server and not in transit).

I was wondering if anyone new of extensions or techniques for optimizing Chrome or Firefox for situations like this, with sites/applications whose pages have a lot of code and a lot of data. We don't need to have a lot of tabs open, but if we could optimize memory and/or processing power and make as much as possible available to the browser in general, or to a specific window or tab, or to a specific page, that might help with performance.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Netsuite's user interface is pretty heavy by default. There are some things you can do to improve the overall response within Netsuite:

- Customize your list options to display a small number of results and with a minimum number of columns. For example, you could make your default Sales Order list view display only the orders from the past 3 months and limit only to show document number, amount and date.
- Customize your forms so the sublists and non essential fields are all moved to secondary subtabs. Example: You can move the item sublist on the Sales Order to a subtab that is not accessible unless you click on it. This way the UI won't load that list until you actually click on the subtab.
- Minimize the number of scripts running on the page. Do your best to de-bloat your Netsuite instance. You can use a free SuiteApp called Application Performance Management (APM) to identify which scripts are taking the most impact in the performance and then you could remove/disable unused bundles/scripts accordingly.

As to the browser, I tend to keep a bunch of tabs open so I have a Chrome extension called ["The Great Suspender"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg) to automatically suspend unused tabs and save some memory.

Comment: Hi Adolfo, Thanks for the input. Those suggestions are great, and some have already been taken (and we can experiment with the rest). We're also  keeping it to just one tab, so the extensions that suspend other tabs can't help much. That's why we're trying to see if there is any way to improve performance by optimizing for memory/processing resources for the entire browser instance. I know it's an odd situation, but hoping to find some tricks. Thanks again!